# Collaborative bookmarking addon for firefox

Tags: firefox, file-sharing, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

I'm searching for a solution that allows me to share a bookmark folder of Firefox inside my company.
I want that people are able to see, edit, organize, delete and add to **the same** bookmarks folder, ideally using the firefox GUI itself. 
I don't want the bookmarks to be public - it's not "social bookmarking" (like delicious).

I don't care if the application has to be installed on a server or if the service is public, as long as it's password protected.

X-marks and the such don't allow *collaborative* bookmarking, their "share" feature just publishes a bookmark list onto a website.

Answer (score 1):

The social bookmarking service Delicious might work if all your users use the same account. You can set bookmarks as "private" in Delicious and they won't be publicly visible, but I'm not sure if it's possible to set all new links to be private by default...